# Codeigniter 2 and Twitter integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

In Codeigniter(version 2.0): Twitter returns a user to

domain.com/connections/twitter/?oauth_token=UXrtdKuLS2N6TCUJdtQAB&oauth_verifier=UXrtdKuLSUXrtdKuLS2N6TCUJdtQAB2N6T

But I keep getting a 404 page. Am I missing something really simple yet important?

Note: Page becomes visible, if I remove '?' from the url.

Comment: At least we need to see some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can utilize a A3M setup, which has all the openid / facebook / twitter pieces built in and working (less tinkering, and you get a working CodeIgniter install)

Details here:

- **https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M**

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable <strike>Query Strings</strike> the GET array in CodeIgniter.

In `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

`allow_get_array` will allow you to use `$_GET` (or rather `$this->input->get()` in your controller).  With this enabled, you can disable query strings (if you want):

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: @Simpanoz: Try to enable `allow_get_array`.

Answer (score 1):

You could $_GET the OAuth token in a file outside of your Codeigniter application and pass it to your controller as a parameter in the URI, like...

outside of your application folder...

```
<?php header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/twitter' . $_GET['oauth_token']);?>
```

This will send your token to the twitter controller, in which you can do

```
$token = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

and then process it how you need.
Are you using any kind of OAuth library such as [jmathai's twitter-async](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) ?